# What is the size of the system buffer in PHP

Tags: php, buffer

I use php_mode (apache2).
output_buffering = Off

I've noted that php starts sending data when I call flush() or when a size of data exceeds 9mb (approximately). 
Also i've noted that people write in different websites about very small sizes(4kb or 8kb), but in my case it's 9mb.

So, the question is:

How can I change the size(9mb)?

Comment: Uhm, ***why*** wouldn't you want PHP to start sending data? After 9mb anyway?

Comment: doesn't matter. I just want to figure out what it is

Comment: Then go look into PHPs memory, **and** Apache memory settings and compile time options.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. I know that it's related to memory settings. I don't know how to find them